# GameKit only records the user's highest score, but I need it to record the lowest - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gamekit

So I'm programming a game for the iPhone that the *best* score is the *lowest* score, but when I submit scores through the GameKit to the Gamecenter leaderboards, only the *highest* score shows up, aka the *worst* score for that player.  Is there a way to make Gamecenter accept lower scores, or a way to check the players score and force gamecenter to replace it if it's lower?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html), you can configure whether the scores are ranked in ascending or descending order through iTunes Connect.

On page 114 of the [iTunes Connect 
Developer Guide 6.6](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), you can see how to change this.

If you want the lowest score to be the best, you'll want to rank in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below link for reference.
Here I am talking about **GKLeaderBoardViewController**.This class is for counting Highest Score.For more details I suggested you to read below link.Thanks

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboardViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html